# why the spring gateway did not enter the custom JwtAuthenticationFilter

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring gateway as the gateway of my project, now I found it did not enter the custom `CustomAddRequestHeaderGatewayFilterFactory`, the code about `CustomAddRequestHeaderGatewayFilterFactory` in my project look like this:

```
  @Component
public class CustomAddRequestHeaderGatewayFilterFactory implements GatewayFilterFactory<CustomAddRequestHeaderGatewayFilterFactory.CustomAddRequestHeaderConfig> {

    private final Class<CustomAddRequestHeaderConfig> configClass = CustomAddRequestHeaderConfig.class;

    @Override
    public List<String> shortcutFieldOrder() {
        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("headerName", "headerValue"));
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(CustomAddRequestHeaderConfig config) {
        return ((exchange, chain) -> {
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest().mutate().headers(httpHeaders -> {
                httpHeaders.set(config.getHeaderName(), config.getHeaderValue());
            }).build();
            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Class<CustomAddRequestHeaderConfig> getConfigClass() {
        return configClass;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomAddRequestHeaderConfig newConfig() {
        return BeanUtils.instantiateClass(this.configClass);
    }

    public static class CustomAddRequestHeaderConfig {

        private String headerName;
        private String headerValue;

        public String getHeaderName() {
            return headerName;
        }

        public void setHeaderName(String headerName) {
            this.headerName = headerName;
        }

        public String getHeaderValue() {
            return headerValue;
        }

        public void setHeaderValue(String headerValue) {
            this.headerValue = headerValue;
        }
    }
}
```

my configuration in `application.properties` look like this:

```
# dolphin music
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=dolphin-music-service
# forward by ip:port way
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=http://10.107.64.246:11014
# forward by service name way
# spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/music/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=CustomAddRequestHeaderGatewayFilterFactory=customHeaderName,customHeaderValue
```

what should I do to make it enter the filter as expect? My request url look like this:

```
https://music-api.example.com/music/playlist/v1/playlist
```

I also tried the config like this:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=CustomAddRequestHeader=customHeaderName,customHeaderValue
```

still did not work.

Comment: what is the URL of the request you are making? don't you need to register this filter in the web security config?
 BTW...make "isApiSecured" static final outside of the function. you don't need to build it on every call.

Comment: I have tweak my code as you said and pasted the url . @TomElias

Comment: its hard to tell just by looking at this. if you have log4j or similar, try turning on debug/trace log for "org.springframework" (or be more specific if you know the correct package). then, make a request and see how spring evaluates the URL and decides what to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is it possible to register route filter in the application.properties config in spring gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69243196/is-it-possible-to-register-route-filter-in-the-application-properties-config-in)